# WPF Navigator control - if source equals?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF navigator control where I'm trying to do something to the effect of the following so I can clean a URL up before going to the clipboard:

```
if (webBrowserWorkflows.Source = "http://testinglink.com")
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to do this Visual Studio tells me: "Cannot convert source type string to System.URI".

With this in mind I've tried:

```
if (webBrowserWorkflows.Source.ToString = "http://testinglink.com")
{
     // do stuff
}
```

However I've had no success. As I'm sure you can tell I'm quite new to C# - this is a bit of a testing ground for me so any documention you can provide with an answer to help me to understand that answer would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new URI object, you can pass your URL into the constructor, this should work:

```
using System;

...

URI myUri = new URI("http://testinglink.com"); 

webBrowserWorkFlows.Source = myUri;
//OR    
webBrowserWorkFlows.Navigate(myUri);
...

if (webBrowserWorkflows.Source == myUri)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: I've done this and now receive: "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.URI' to 'bool'?

Comment: What type is 'webBrowserWorkflows'?

Comment: WebBrowser (called this in the WPF toolbox also)

Comment: It is because you are setting it inside the condition of an if loop, are you trying to test if the browser went to the location successfully?

Comment: No, I want to try if the browser is currently on the page http://testing.com, if it's not it will handle differently. Thoughts?

Comment: Excellent / solved - thank-you. You are a king amongst men and all should praise you!